# What can be found on the "terminal" on the Jurassic World promotional website?

Tags: jurassic-park, online-resources, jurassic-world

For the promotion of *Jurassic World*, [a website was made for *Masrani Global*](http://www.masraniglobal.com), the company operating the theme park. On that site, there is [a simulated computer terminal](http://www.masraniglobal.com/terminal/system/desktop.html) one can log onto. What can be found on that terminal?

---

The link takes you straight to a "logged in session" on the terminal. Should you want to go through the main site and log in yourself, the password is (case-insensitive)

> Indominus

Comment: Love how the HTML tile of the terminal is "Masrani Backdoor" :-)

Comment: What is the password?

Comment: @MadPhysicist (so as to not spoil the password for those who wish to figure it out themselves I have used Rot13 to hide the solution, contained in the rest of this comment):  Lbh pna svaq gur cnffjbeq ol ercynpvat "qrfxgbc.ugzy" jvgu "grezvany.wf". Guvf jvyy fubj lbh fbzr wdhrel, jvgu ng fbzr cbvag gur grkg `a.zngpu(/^\f*` evtug nsgre gur * vg jvyy gryy lbh gur cnffjbeq.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've edited it in.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After downloading the Javascript powering it, it seems it has the following commands and subcommands:

- `help` displays a help message (also works in submenus)
- `assets` allows to query the assets: the animals kept at the park. Names of animals can be entered, displaying a translation of its name and opening a (now defunct) link to the animal on JurassicWorld.com.

  - `ankylosaurus`
  - `apatosaurus`
  - `baryonyx`
  - `dimorphodon`
  - `edmontosaurus`
  - `gallimimus`
  - `indominus rex` or `indominus`
  - `metriacanthosaurus`
  - `microceratus`
  - `mosasaurus`
  - `pachycephalosaurus`
  - `parasaurolophus`
  - `pteranodon`
  - `stegosaurus`
  - `suchomimus`
  - `triceratops`
  - `tyrannosaurus rex` or `tyrannosaurus`
  - `velociraptor` or `raptor`
- `query` allows to query objects, which seems a catch-all for persons, locations, companies, and objects.

  - `diabolus rex`

    > ERROR: DID YOU MEAN 'AXIS BOULDER'?
  - `simon masrani` or `masrani`

    > NAME: MASRANI, SIMON
    > POSITION: CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER, MASRANI GLOBAL CORPORATION
  - `henry wu` or `wu`

    > NAME: WU, HENRY
    > POSITION: LEAD GENETIC BIOLOGIST, INTERNATIONAL GENETIC TECHNOLOGIES, INC.
  - `colin trevorrow` or `trevorrow`

    > NAME: TREVORROW, COLIN
    > POSITION: DIRECTOR, SAFETY (NOT GUARANTEED)
  - `derek connolly` or `derek` or `connolly`

    > NAME: CONNOLLY, DEREK
    > POSITION: EMPLOYEE OF THE MONTH
  - `isla nublar` or `nublar`

    > NAME: ISLA NUBLAR
    > LOCATION: 120 MILES OFF THE COAST OF COSTA RICA
    > DESCRIPTION: HOME OF JURASSIC WORLD
  - `isla sorna` or `sorna`
  - `isla pena` or `pena`
  - `isla muerta` or `muerta`
  - `isla matanceros` or `matanceros`
  - `isla tacano` or `tacano`
  - `feathers`
  - `dna`
  - `amber`
  - `barbasol`

    > NAME: BARBASOL
    > LOCATION: UNKNOWN
  - `visitors centre`
- `timeline` shows a relevant item for selected years, displaying "ERROR: NO TIMELINE DATA" for all other years.

  - `1525`

    > ISLA NUBLAR DISCOVERED BY DIEGO FERNANDEZ
  - `1526`

    > MEURTES ARCHIPELAGO DISCOVERED (DISPUTED)
  - `1913`

    > JOHN PARKER HAMMOND BORN IN EDINBURGH, SCOTLAND
  - `1930`

    > SANJAY MASRANI BORN IN BOMBAY (MUMBAI), BRITISH INDIA
  - `1967`

    > SIMON MASRANI BORN IN BOMBAY (MUMBAI), INDIA
  - `1969`

    > JOHN HAMMOND'S 'ANIMAL KINGDOM' OPENS IN NAIROBI, KENYA
  - `1973`

    > MASCOM NETWORK ESTABLISHED IN BOMBAY (MUMBAI), INDIA
  - `1975`

    > INTERNATIONAL GENETIC TECHNOLOGIES, INC. ESTABLISHED IN SAN DIEGO, USA
  - `1979`

    > MASCOM UNVEILS CONCEPT FOR FIBER-OPTIC COMMUNICATIONS
  - `1982`

    > ISLA SORNA 'SITE B' LEASED FROM COSTA RICAN GOVERNMENT
  - `1983`

    > CONSTRUCTION BEGINS ON 'JURASSIC PARK: SAN DIEGO'
  - `1984`

    > FIRST TEST FERTILIZATION OF ARTIFICIAL OVUM
    > TATSUO TECHNOLOGY ESTABLISHED IN TOKYO, JAPAN
  - `1985`

    > 'JURASSIC PARK: SAN DIEGO' DECOMMISSIONED
    > ISLA NUBLAR LEASED FROM COSTA RICAN GOVERNMENT
  - `1986`

    > FIRST DINOSAUR SUCCESSFULLY CLONED AT 'SITE B'
  - `1987`

    > LAST REMAINING BRIBRI TRIBE DESCENDANT RESETTLED OFF ISLA NUBLAR
  - `1988`

    > CONSTRUCTION OF 'JURASSIC PARK' BEGINS
    > FIRST MATURE ANIMALS MOVED FROM 'SITE B' TO ISLA NUBLAR
  - `1992`

    > SANJAY MASRANI PASSES AWAY
    > SIMON MASRANI NAMED CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER, MASCOM NETWORK
  - `1993`

    > FURTHER INFORMATION: RESTRICTED ACCESS
  - `1994`

    > FURTHER INFORMATION: RESTRICTED ACCESS
  - `1995`

    > DR. HENRY WU PUBLISHES 'THE NEXT STEP: AN EVOLUTION OF GOD'S CONCEPTS'
  - `1996`

    > MASRANI OIL INDUSTRIES ESTABLISHED IN ABU DHABI, UAE
    > DATA ANALYSYS ESTABLISHED IN JOHANNESBERG, SOUTH AFRICA
  - `1997`

    > JOHN PARKER HAMMOND PASSES AWAY
    > DR. HENRY WU CREATES 'KARACOSIS WUTANIS'
    > FURTHER INFORMATION: RESTRICTED ACCESS
  - `1998`

    > INTERNATIONAL GENETIC TECHNOLOGIES, INC. ACQUIRED BY MASRANI GLOBAL
  - `1999`

    > MASRANI GLOBAL ACQUIRES LIMITED ACCESS TO ISLA NUBLAR AND ISLA SORNA
    > FURTHER INFORMATION: RESTRICTED ACCESS
  - `2000`

    > DR. HENRY WU BEGINS WORK ON 'JURASSIC WORLD' PROJECT
    > AXIS BOULDER ESTABLISHED IN DUBAI, UAE
  - `2001`

    > 'FLYING REPTILE CLEANUP' HEADED BY VIC HOSKINS
    > FURTHER INFORMATION: RESTRICTED ACCESS
  - `2002`

    > TIMACK CONSTRUCTION ESTABLISHED IN SAN JOSÉ, COSTA RICA
    > CONSTRUCTION BEGINS ON 'JURASSIC WORLD'
  - `2003`

    > MEDIXAL HEALTH ESTABLISHED IN NEW YORK, USA
  - `2004`

    > 'JURASSIC WORLD' CONSTRUCTION COMPLETED
    > ASSETS MOVED FROM ISLA SORNA TO ISLA NUBLAR
  - `2005`

    > OPENING OF 'JURASSIC WORLD' ON ISLA NUBLAR
  - `2007`

    > AEROSPACE DYNAMIX ESTABLISHED IN TOULOUSE, FRANCE
  - `2011`

    > TATSUO TECHNOLOGY ACQUIRED BY MASRANI GLOBAL CORPORATION
  - `2012`

    > IBRIS PROJECT BEGINS DEVELOPMENT
    > HYBRID 'INDOMINUS REX' HATCHED
    > FURTHER INFORMATION: RESTRICTED ACCESS
  - `2014`

    > 'MARTEL' FACILITY ESTABLISHED IN SIBERIA, RUSSIA
    > INTERNATIONAL GENETIC TECHNOLOGIES, INC. HOUSES WORLD'S MOST COMPLETE GENOMIC LIBRARY
  - `2015`

    > UPDATE PENDING
- `inbox` allows to read a number of messages by different senders and to different recipients.

  - `read` shows an overview of the messages.
  - `01102015`

    > ---NEW MESSAGE---
    >
    > FROM: HOSKINS, VIC
    > TO: [UNDISCLOSED RECIPIENTS]
    > DATE: 01/10/2015 1215 CST
    > SUBJECT: INSTALLATION
    > MESSAGE: MASCOM NETWORK ENGINEERS WILL BE ON SITE INSTALLING NEW SCANNING HARDWARE IN THE NORTH OF THE ISLAND PAST THE RESTRICTED ZONE ON JANUARY 30 0800 CST. ALL INGEN SECURITY STAFF PLEASE BE ON STANDBY TO ASSIST.
    >
    > ---END MESSAGE---
  - `12242014`

    > ---NEW MESSAGE---
    >
    > FROM: MASRANI, SIMON
    > TO: [UNDISCLOSED RECIPIENT]
    > DATE: 12/24/2014 0940 CST
    > SUBJECT: RE: INDOMINUS REX
    > MESSAGE: UNFORTUNATELY MY FACE IS NEEDED AT SEVERAL OTHER MEETINGS AND EVENTS OVER THE COMING SIX MONTHS. I WON'T BE ABLE TO SEE THE FRUITS OF YOUR LABOR UNTIL THE END OF MAY OR EARLY JUNE. SINCERE APOLOGIES. SIMON.
    >
    > ---END MESSAGE---
  - `11152014`

    > ---NEW MESSAGE---
    >
    > FROM: WU, HENRY
    > TO: [UNDISCLOSED RECIPIENTS]
    > DATE: 11/15/2014 1105 CST
    > SUBJECT: MARTEL
    > MESSAGE: CONGRATULATIONS TO THE MARTEL TEAM ON THEIR OPENING! THIS IS OUR FIRST STEP INTO CREATING THE MOST COMPREHENSIVE BIOLOGICAL LIBRARY THE WORLD HAS EVER SEEN. OBVIOUS RUMORS HAVE ALREADY BEGUN CIRCULATING ABOUT OUR INTENTIONS BUT I WANT THE CORE TEAM TO KNOW THAT WE'RE JUST COLLECTING AND ARCHIVING FOR NOW. I'VE SPOKEN WITH SIMON AND HE HAS EXPRESSED HIS UTMOST DELIGHT THAT WE'LL BEGIN WORK ON THIS.
    >
    > ---END MESSAGE---
  - `05172013`

    > ---NEW MESSAGE---
    >
    > FROM: GRADY, OWEN
    > TO: [UNDISCLOSED RECIPIENT]
    > DATE: 05/17/2013 0955 CST
    > SUBJECT: HELP
    > MESSAGE: THEIR PACK DYNAMIC IS MUCH MORE COMPLICATED THAN WE FIRST THOUGHT AND I'M STARTING TO THINK YOU'RE NOT WEIGHING UP THE GRAVITY OF THAT. WE CANNOT BURY OUR HEADS IN THE SAND AND HOPE FOR THE BEST WITH THIS, SO I'M GOING TO NEED SOME HELP. I HAVE AN OLD FRIEND IN FRANCE, BARRY, WHO CAN ASSIST. I'LL SEND HIM YOUR NUMBER TO INTRODUCE YOU. IF WE'RE TO STUDY THESE ANIMALS AND LEARN HOW THEY WORK THEN WE SHOULDN'T ASSUME TO GAIN THEIR CO-OPERATION WITH JUST A FEW SNACKS. REMEMBER, THEY CAN TALK TO EACH OTHER. JUST A TIP, VIC.
    >
    > ---END MESSAGE---
  - `04042008`

    > ---NEW MESSAGE---
    >
    > FROM: MASRANI, SIMON
    > TO: [UNDISCLOSED RECIPIENT]
    > DATE: 04/04/2008 1720 CST
    > SUBJECT: NEW OPPORTUNITY
    > MESSAGE: HENRY. I'VE JUST COME OUT OF A MEETING AND THE BOARD ARE UNANIMOUS IN THEIR DESIRE FOR A NEW PARK ATTRACTION TO SATISFY OUR INVESTORS. SOMETHING BIGGER, SCARIER, COOLER. ANY NEW SPECIES COME TO MIND? YOU HAVE MY FULL AUTHORIZATION. SIMON.
    >
    > ---END MESSAGE---
  - `05302005`

    > ---NEW MESSAGE---
    >
    > FROM: MASRANI, SIMON
    > TO: [UNDISCLOSED RECIPIENTS]
    > DATE: 05/30/2005 1530 CST
    > SUBJECT: GRAND OPENING
    > MESSAGE: I JUST WANTED TO SEND A QUICK MESSAGE TO THANK EACH AND EVERY ONE OF YOU FOR ALL THE EFFORT YOU'VE PUT INTO MAKING JURASSIC WORLD COME TO LIFE. WE HAVE A SAYING BACK HOME IN INDIA, 'DER AAYE DURUST AAYE' OR 'BETTER LATE THAN NEVER'. IT'S TIME WE MAKE HISTORY. HAMMOND WOULD BE PROUD. NAMASTE. SIMON.
    >
    > ---END MESSAGE---
  - `06082004`

    > ---NEW MESSAGE---
    >
    > FROM: MCCLURE, JAMES
    > TO: [UNDISCLOSED RECIPIENT]
    > DATE: 06/08/2004 2050 CST
    > SUBJECT: RE: JW SYSTEMS CHECK
    > MESSAGE: I'VE MANAGED TO ISOLATE THE ANOMALY. I WOULD SAY THE SYSTEM IS NOW WATERTIGHT. I'LL GIVE HOSKINS A CALL AND SEE IF HE CAN SPOT ANYTHING THAT NEEDS UPDATING. YOU KNOW HOW HE HAS AN EYE FOR DETAIL. MIGHT HELP.
    >
    > ---END MESSAGE---
  - `10231999`

    > ---NEW MESSAGE---
    >
    > FROM: MASRANI, SIMON
    > TO: [UNDISCLOSED RECIPIENT]
    > DATE: 10/23/1999 0005 CST
    > SUBJECT: JURASSIC PLOP
    > MESSAGE: I'M DISSATISFIED WITH THE NAME. 'PARK' FEELS SMALL, TOO 1980'S, NOT TO MENTION IT HAS A LOT OF WEIGHT AND BAD PRESS AROUND IT. I'VE BEEN SCRIBBLING NOTES ON MY FLIGHTS COMING UP WITH POSSIBLE TITLES, AND I'M THINKING 'WORLD'. WELCOME TO 'JURASSIC WORLD'! THOUGHTS? OTHERS IDEAS INCLUDED ... JURASSIC ISLAND, THE LOST WORLD, PREHISTORIC WORLD, JURASSIC LAND, DINO ISLAND, CRETASIA ISLAND, ROAMING REPTILES, DINOSPHERE, ... GIANT CHICKEN ISLAND?
    >
    > ---END MESSAGE---
  - `01101998`

    > ---NEW MESSAGE---
    >
    > FROM: MASRANI, SIMON
    > TO: [UNDISCLOSED RECIPIENT]
    > DATE: 01/10/1998 1215 CST
    > SUBJECT: THE NEXT TEN YEARS
    > MESSAGE: FANCY MEETING ME FOR LUNCH THIS THURSDAY? STRICTLY BUSINESS. SIMON.
    >
    > ---END MESSAGE---
- `archive` allows to read a number of log messages, similar to the inbox messages.

  - `read` shows an overview of the messages.
  - `06062009`

    > ---BEGIN LOG---
    >
    > OWNER: MASRANI, SIMON
    > DATE: 06/06/2009 0800 CST
    > SUBJECT: NAMUMKIN KUCH BHI NAHI
    > NOTES: I REMEMBER THE FIRST TIME I HELD A BABY DINOSAUR, AN INFANT PARASAUROLOPHUS IN 1999 DURING MY VISIT TO OVERSEE OUR RECENTLY PURCHASED INGEN. I REMEMBER THINKING THIS WAS THE RESULT OF PURE IMAGINATION REINFORCED BY THE UNDERSTANDING THAT NOTHING IS IMPOSSIBLE. PEOPLE OFTEN TALK ABOUT HOW MAN CANNOT FLY WITHOUT AN AIRCRAFT, HOWEVER IF YOU REMOVE GRAVITY MAN CAN FLY WITHOUT AID OF ANYTHING. IT'S ALL ABOUT PERSPECTIVE. I KNOW NOW, MORE THAN EVER, THAT OUR SPECIES HAS UNLIMITED CAPABILITIES. HOLDING THAT YOUNG ANIMAL WAS A WAKE UP CALL. IF WE DREAM OF IT, WE CAN ACHIEVE IT. NOW ONLY ONE QUESTION REMAINS: WHAT IS NEXT FOR INGEN? I BELIEVE HENRY WU HAS AN ANSWER.
    >
    > ---END LOG---
  - `02202003`

    > ---BEGIN LOG---
    >
    > OWNER: WU, HENRY
    > DATE: 02/20/2003 1410 CST
    > SUBJECT: RUFFLED FEATHERS
    > NOTES: I'M CALLING THIS THE 'COMMON COLD OF GENETICS'. WE CAN'T CURE THIS ONE SOON I'M SURE. BECAUSE WE'RE ACTIVELY MANIPULATING AND MUTATING THE ANIMALS' GENES, ADDING FROG, BIRD AND REPTILE DNA, WE CREATE WHAT IS KNOWN AS 'NULL ALLELE'. THE DINOSAURS CANNOT LIVE WITHOUT SOMETHING ADDED TO THEIR CODE SO FOR NOW WE'RE STUCK WITH SCALES. MAYBE MY RESEARCH INTO GENE SPLICING WILL UNEARTH THIS PROBLEM, IT CERTAINLY PROVED ITS LIMITLESS CAPABILITIES WITH THAT ACCIDENT WE LEFT ON SORNA.
    >
    > ---END LOG---
  - `04192002`

    > ---BEGIN LOG---
    >
    > OWNER: HOSKINS, VIC
    > DATE: 04/19/2002 1910 CST
    > SUBJECT: WEEK 3
    > NOTES: I WAS IMPRESSED WITH THE TEAM TODAY. HELL, STARING A SEVEN TON PREDATOR IN THE EYES IS NO EASY JOB. THESE THINGS ARE BIGGER THAN YOU'D EXPECT! LET'S JUST HOPE TIMACK KNOWS HOW TO BUILD STRONG PADDOCKS.
    >
    > ---END LOG---
  - `08252000`

    > ---BEGIN LOG---
    >
    > OWNER: WU, HENRY
    > DATE: 08/25/2000 1355 CST
    > SUBJECT: IRON STORES
    > NOTES: TECHNOLOGY NEVER CEASES TO AMAZE ME. JUST A DECADE AGO NO ONE HAD BELIEVED WE'D HOLD THE TECHNOLOGY WE USE TODAY. MOORE'S LAW IS THRIVING. OUR RESEARCHERS IN SAN DIEGO (BRIDGES & CURTIS, ET AL.) HAVE GIVEN ME THE NEWS THAT OUR PROTOTYPE IRON ANALYZER READ INTO OUR RECENTLY UNCOVERED FOSSILIZED MOSASAUR SKELETON AND HAS SHOWN SIGNS OF TRACEABLE DNA FRAGMENTS. WHILST IT IS STILL MUCH TOO EARLY TO TELL, I BELIEVE THIS MAY BE OUR ONLY MEANS TO RECREATING AQUATIC LIFE IN THE ABSENCE OF CULICIDAE.
    >
    > ---END LOG---
  - `05211997`

    > ---BEGIN LOG---
    >
    > OWNER: WU, HENRY
    > DATE: 05/21/1997 0745 CST
    > SUBJECT: KARACOSIS WUTANSIS
    > NOTES: SUCCESS! SOMETHING THAT I THOUGHT WAS DECADES AWAY WAS ACHIEVED IN A MERE FOUR YEARS: THE ABILITY TO COMBINE MULTIPLE SPECIES OF GENETIC LIFE INTO A SINGLE ENVIRONMENT. A BRAND NEW SPECIES OF LIFE. THE INTERNATIONAL SOCIETY OF GENETICISTS ARE ALREADY NAMING IT IN MY HONOR: KARACOSIS WUTANSIS. IF ONLY HAMMOND WAS WELL ENOUGH TO HAVE COME AND SEEN THIS. LOOKS LIKE I'LL HAVE TO UPDATE MY BOOK.
    >
    > ---END LOG---
  - `05121994`

    > ---BEGIN LOG---
    >
    > OWNER: WU, HENRY
    > DATE: 05/12/1994 1215 CST
    > SUBJECT: LYSINE
    > NOTES: THERE MUST BE A HICCUP IN THE LYSINE CONTINGENCY SOMEWHERE. THE ANIMALS HAVE NOT PERISHED. WHAT'S MORE ASTONISHING IS THAT THEY'RE BREEDING. I'VE SEEN THE NESTS MYSELF. ONE CAN ONLY ASSUME INCLUSIONS FROM HYPEROLIUS VIRIDIFLAVUS WERE TO BLAME. COMPLETELY UNPRECEDENTED IN MY FIELD OF RESEARCH. LIFE FOUND A WAY?
    >
    > ---END LOG---
  - `02131992`

    > ---BEGIN LOG---
    >
    > OWNER: WU, HENRY
    > DATE: 02/13/1992 1410 CST
    > SUBJECT: COLLECTIVE INTELLIGENCE
    > NOTES: VELOCIRAPTOR SUBJECTS HAVE BEEN DISPLAYING HIGH LEVELS OF SHARED INTELLIGENCE AS A RESULT OF A THREE STEP PROCESS INVOLVING COGNITION, COOPERATION, AND COORDINATION. THE COLLECTIVE IQ IS STAGGERING. PERHAPS MORE ALARMING ARE SCANS OF THEIR TEMPORAL LOBE DISPLAYING HIGH LEVELS OF ACTIVITY RESPONSIBLE FOR MEMORY, ORGANIZATION AND SEQUENCING, AND RECEPTIVE LANGUAGE.
    >
    > ---END LOG---
  - `09201991`

    > ---BEGIN LOG---
    >
    > OWNER: WU, HENRY
    > DATE: 09/20/1991 2205 CST
    > SUBJECT: KARYOLYSIS
    > NOTES: DESPITE INITIAL TESTS SHOWING PROMISING RESULTS, SUBJECTS 4X, 6X AND 7X (VELOCIRAPTOR) ALL FAILED WITHIN 6 DAYS DUE TO KARYOLYSIS: COMPLEX CHROMATIN MOLECULES COLLAPSING DURING INTERPHASE. WE BELIEVE THIS WAS DUE TO INCOMPATIBLE GENETIC STRUCTURES IN DENDROBATES LEUCOMELAS; AN INTERESTING THOUGHT AS DILOPHOSAURUS HAS SHOWN GOOD RESULTS WITH XL-22(728)[REGION 1]. A POSSIBLE SOLUTION HAS BEEN FOUND IN HYPEROLIUS VIRIDIFLAVUS.
    >
    > ---END LOG---
- `ping` (not listed in the help) simply replies "pong"
- `ls` shows the file names of three images. Typing its name displays the image in a new window.
- `ibris.jpg`
- `meme.jpg`
- `timack.jpg`

Some questions are answered here, such as how they managed to extract DNA from aquatic animals (not many mosquitos under water) and why the dinosaurs didn't have feathers (frog DNA).

Comment: I may add the full responses later, but that's a bit more work.

Comment: 'ping (not listed in the help) simply replies "pong"'... as it should.

Comment: All that fancy cloning tech, and they couldn't afford a log system that supported anything but ALLCAPS. I guess it's a bit charming though if you pretend you're reading logs inside a retro RPG. :-)

Comment: @Mentalist "It's case insensitive, so it's _not_ a UNIX system! I know this!"